# Decorator execution?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Playing with decorator, founds something strange: I have something simple as below (a decorator to register the function to a list:

```
stored_f = []

def register(f):
    stored_f.append(f.__name__)
    return f

@register
def say_hello(name):
    print(f"Hello {name}")

@register
def ur_awesome(name):
    return f"{name}, you are awesome!"
```

I thought the above code will do nothing (it will print nothing out), because I haven't executed anything, but actually a print command "print(stored_f)" will have a output:

```
['say_hello', 'ur_awesome']
```

Meaning the line "stored_f.append(f.__name__)" in register() actually got executed, twice. This is weird to me.

I tried to define a wrapper() inside register like normally and then return wrapper, the issue will go away. But still I don't understand why the above code will partially execute the decorator without calling it.

Comment: Why did you think that *wouldn't* get executed? It doesn't *"partially execute the decorator without calling it"*; it *entirely* executes the decorator, by calling it.

Comment: "because I haven't executed anything" - but `@register` executes `register`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because I haven't executed anything, it is all definitions only. Just like I said last, if I put a wrapper inside register, it will do absolutely nothing as I expected.

Comment: "if I put a wrapper inside register, it will do absolutely nothing as I expected" - because you executed `register`, not the wrapper.

Comment: Monica, isn't that only @register() will execute, @register only move the 'pointer' from original function to decorator, without execution?

Comment: `@addRegister def foo(..)....` is the same as typing `foo = addRegister(foo)`.  Python also performs a small bit of magic so that the resulting new value of `foo` has the right name.  But `addRegister` gets called as soon as it sees the function definition.

Comment: @FrankYellin: "Python also performs a small bit of magic so that the resulting new value of foo has the right name" - if you're talking about adjusting `__name__`, that doesn't happen automatically. You have to do it yourself if you want that, usually by calling `functools.wraps`.

Comment: *"if I put a wrapper inside register, it will do absolutely nothing"* - that's not true, the *definition of the wrapper* will be executed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK, I stand corrected, yes, the definition will happen, but the list "stored_f" is still empty, which I understand and expected it.

Comment: The body of `register` is executed. Whatever you do in there gets done. If you change the definition of `register` so that you don't append to `stored_f` in it, then yes it will still be empty. The decorator syntax is basically shorthand for `say_hello = register(say_hello)`.

Comment: Jon, Monica and Frank, thanks, I made peace with myself now, :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing and running a Python file executes it and adding the decorator with `@register` executes the decorator.

So, even though your script only consists of the variable declaration, the decorator and two function definitions, when you run it, both those definitions will be executed (defining the functions) and decorator functions on them will be executed, so that the functions are correctly decorated.

Added after your comment: consider this:

```
stored_f = []

def register(f):
    stored_f.append(f.__name__)
    print('it runs!')
    return f

@register
def say_hello(name):
    print(f"Hello {name}")

@register
def ur_awesome(name):
    return f"{name}, you are awesome!"
```

You'll find that, if you run this script, the output is:

```
it runs!
it runs!
```

All the code in the decorator runs and you just return the same function it received, so `f` will work just the same before and after.

Also, if you add `say_hello("john")` to the end of that script, you'll find the decorator does not run again, only the function runs again.

Also, compare this:

```
stored_f = []

def register(f):
    stored_f.append(f.__name__)
    def decorated_f(*args):
        print('it runs!')
        f(*args)
    return decorated_f

@register
def say_hello(name):
    print(f"Hello {name}")

say_hello("john")
say_hello("pete")
```

This results in:

```
it runs!
Hello john
it runs!
Hello pete
```

Perhaps that's closer to what you were expecting. Note that the decorator doesn't return the original function, it returns the new one.

Comment: I thought, but correct me if I am wrong: @register does NOT execute the decorator, only @register() or say_hello() (note the parentheses in both cases) will execute. ALSO, if I try to follow your logic, why python only executed firs tline in register, then stopped?

Comment: I've added some examples which I hope clarify the situation for you.

Comment: You're welcome - if you feel the answer is good enough for your question, please click the checkmark as well, so that the question appears as answered, which helps others looking for answer, or for answered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Grimar's answer, I did the following, may explain it from another angle, at least to myself:

```
def do_twice(f):
    print('This will be executed anyway')
    def wrapper():
        f()
        f()
    return wrapper

@do_twice
def say_hello():
    print('This is say hello')
```

output:

```
This will be executed anyway
```

if I run:

```
say_hello()
```

output:

```
This is say hello
This is say hello
```